# CodeReady Containers not starting

Tags: openshift

I'm using the latest version of CodeReady Containers but after the first run, it doesn't start anymore:

```
>crc start -p pull-secret.txt 
Is '/Applications/CodeReady Containers.app' running? Cannot reach daemon API: Get 
"http://unix/api/version": dial unix /Users/user/.crc/crc-http.sock: connect: 
connection refused
```

I tried to delete and cleanup but it doesn't help.

```
>crc status --log-level debug
DEBU CodeReady Containers version: 1.38.0+659b2cbd 
DEBU OpenShift version: 4.9.12 (bundle installed at /Applications/CodeReady Containers.app/Contents/Resources/crc_hyperkit_4.9.12.crcbundle) 
DEBU Running 'crc status'                         
DEBU Checking file: /Users/user/.crc/machines/crc/.crc-exist 
Machine does not exist. Use 'crc start' to create it
>crc config view
- autostart-tray                        : false
- consent-telemetry                     : no
- cpus                                  : 6
- memory                                : 16384
- pull-secret-file                      : /Users/user/openshift/pull-secret.txt
```

Same issue appears on both MacOS and Windows. Any idea on how to solve? Or alternatively other ways to install Openshift locally for free?

Comment: hmm not sure if it might be of interest https://www.giters.com/code-ready/crc/issues/2687

Comment: CRC_DISABLE_UPDATE_CHECK=true doesn't help either.

Comment: The URL you linked is not working. I already tried crc cleanup and then crc start but I get the same error.

Comment: This should be fixed by github.com/code-ready/crc/pull/2722 can you try crc cleanup and then start fresh? Other than that, how does the same issue appear on a Windows PC , when the error is clearly macOS specific for a *.app process

Answer (score 0):

In one shell window run "crc daemon". Open another shell window and run "crc start".

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this bug by enabling the Hyper-V. So you need to run the following command in your PowerShell console (as admin):

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All
```

and than:

```
run crc start
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v